# Correctness of this grade 9 Math quiz

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

So, I'm a grade 9 student. My Math teacher marked first 2 questions wrong. I'm not sure why. I believe they are correct. Please tell me if they are. I need to show this page to principle tomorrow.

The first question reads: $\frac{p}{3} - \frac{2p}{2} = \frac{5}{6}-p$

The second question reads: $\frac{x}{3} - \frac{3}{7} = \frac{4x}{7} + \frac{5}{3}$

Comment: This is quite hard to read, as you've marked up the problems.  If, say, the first one reads $\frac p3 -\frac {2p}2=\frac 56-p$ then we clear denominators by multiplying through by $6$ to get $2p-6p=5-6p\implies 2p=5\implies p=\frac 52$, which is the same as your result (though you do not simplify your fraction).  But, as I say, it is very hard to read the original problem (and, of course, $\frac {2p}2$ seems a bit unlikely).

Comment: Your answers to the first two are incorrect because you haven't reduced the fractions. 30/12 reduces to 5/2, and -924/105 reduces to -44/5. The 2 points you have received seem to be from those first two questions, where you have got 1 point on each of them for the correct value, but not got the second point because you didn't reduce the fractions.

Comment: You have $12p = 30$ which seems to be true.  And $p = \frac {30}{12}$ which is true but not reduced to lowest terms so incomplete.  But then you put an equal sign between them to write "$12p =30 = p=\frac {30}{12}$" which is a meaningless and wrong run on expression.  $30 \ne p$ and $12p\ne p$ and $30\ne =\frac {30}{12}$ and $12p \ne \frac {30}{12}$.  But the statement  "$12p =30 = p=\frac {30}{12}$" says that *all* those things are true.

Comment: Also, I would take off for the extraneous equal signs.  If a student leaves $2x=6=x=3$, I nuke him for asserting that 6 equals 3.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{p}{3}-\frac{2p}{2}=\frac{5}{6}-p$$
$$\frac{p}{3}-p=\frac{5}{6}-p$$
$$\frac{p}{3}=\frac{5}{6}$$
$$6p=15$$
$$p=\frac{15}{6}$$
$$p=\frac{5}{2}$$

Notice that the directions said ***simplify*** all fractions. Your answers were correct, but you didn't properly follow the directions. That's where you lost points. The second question can be solved in a similar manner and you made the same mistake.

Also, just an aside: try to find clever ways to avoid crazy fractions that are hard to simplify.